# From-name in SingleEmailMessage

Tags: singleemailmessage

I am working on a process that sends mail through apex. I am facing the issue that I am not able to display the sender name. I am using mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce team') but still it is not displaying this name. The sender in the mail is showing my username.

I'm using the following code:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
mail.setTemplateID(templateId.Id);  
mail.setTargetObjectId(usr.Id); 
mail.setReplyTo('donotreply@GMF.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce team');
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
allmsg.add(mail);
```

Comment: Here I am not using setOrgWideEmailAddressId()

Comment: Then use a custom setting for it.

Comment: could you please tell me how to use custom setting for it ?

Comment: I don't think you can control how email clients render this name. I suspect that the client you're viewing this in takes the name related to the contact you have for that from address, which you can't control the from address except by using an org-wide email address.